# Flutter mongo db object id to string

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, objectid

I Am building an application with Flutter and MongoDB. There is a thing that I am not understanding.

When I retrieve the user data I am setting my object by passing the `Map<String, dynamic>?` variable to the function `fromJson`.

The problem is that the id is getting all the syntax of mongo like: `ObjectId("62096f5cbbf77abdf2ee00e4")` instead I want only `"62096f5cbbf77abdf2ee00e4"` to have a cleaner syntax.

Is that possible?

```
User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : 
    id = json['_id'].toString(),
    name = json['name'].toString();
```

**edit with solution**

I think that the best solution is to use the custom type from mongo_dart ObjectId to save the id.

Comment: You could also substring the ID out of it like: id.substring(10, id.length - 2)), which gives you '62096f5cbbf77abdf2ee00e4'

Comment: Yea but I think is better to use the ObjectId type since mongo_dart provide it. In this way the code is optimised.

Comment: Yup - I agree; it's just in the event that you don't have access to the backend to make changes to it, but if you do, definitely.

Answer (score 0):

The `_id` is ObjectId.

```
ObjectId objectId = collections.first['_id'];
  print("objectId: ${objectId.id}");
  print("oid: ${objectId.$oid}");
  print("dateTime: ${objectId.dateTime}");
  print("hashCode: ${objectId.hashCode}");
```

The result like:

```
objectId: BsonBinary(62096f5cbbf77abdf2ee00e4)
oid: 62096f5cbbf77abdf2ee00e4
dateTime: 2022-10-21 00:00:00.000
hashCode: 123456789
```

You want `$oid`. I think you can change this line

```
id = json['_id'].toString(),
```

to

```
id = json['_id'].$oid.toString(),
//or
id = (json['_id'] as ObjectId).$oid.toString(),
```